How to Apply Image Augmentations in TensorFlow Pipeline for Large Dataset?
I have a dataset of images, each containing a 1 to 5letter word. I want to use deep learning to classify the characters that make up the word in each image. The labels for these images are formatted as follows:
totalcharacter_indexoffirstchar_indexofsecondchar_.._indexoflastchar
I'm trying to load these images into TensorFlow pipelines to reduce complexity due to memory constraints. Below is my code for loading and processing images and labels from directory:
def process_img(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=1) 
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32) 
    target_shape = [695, 1204]
    image = tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(image, target_shape[0], target_shape[1])
    
    # Encode the label
    encoded_label = tf.py_function(func=encode_label, inp=[label], Tout=tf.float32)
    encoded_label.set_shape([5, len(urdu_alphabets)])
    
    return image, encoded_label
input_dir = '/kaggle/input/dataset/Data/*'
images_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(input_dir, shuffle=True)

train_count = int(tf.math.round(len(images_ds) * 0.8))
train_ds = images_ds.take(train_count)
test_ds = images_ds.skip(train_count)
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.map(process_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.batch(32)
train_ds = train_ds.cache()
test_ds = test_ds.cache()
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(len(train_ds))
test_ds = test_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
print(train_ds)
print(test_ds)

The train_ds looks like this:
<_PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 695, 1204, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5, 39), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>
Now, I want to apply simple augmentations on the images such as rotation, shear, erosion, and dilation. I initially used the following function:
def augment(image, label):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
    image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation(image, rg=15, row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2, fill_mode='nearest', cval=0.0, interpolation_order=1)
    image = tf.image.random_zoom(image, [0.85, 0.85])
    image = tf.image.random_shear(image, 0.3)
    image = tf.image.random_shift(image, 0.1, 0.1)
    return image, label

train_augmented_ds = train_ds.map(augment, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_augmented_ds = train_augmented_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

However, many of these functions in tf.image are deprecated. How can I apply these augmentations on images in a TensorFlow pipeline in an efficient way?
Note: I can perform these augmentations by loading images without TensorFlow pipelines using NumPy arrays, but my dataset is very large (1.1 million images), so I need an efficient way to do this.

You can use ImageDataGenerator:
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


ImageDataGenerator is also deprecated.

You can use layers, e.g. the RandomRotation layer. I think every operation you listed expect for random shear is available as a TensorFlow layer now. Random shear is available as a layer in the keras-cv package.
You could add these layers at the beginning of your model directly, or create a separate model with these preprocessing layers, which you can add as a sub-model. By default, these augmentations are only applied in training, so your test set (or training set in model.evaluate(train)) will not be affected.

But if we add them at the beginning of the model, only augmented images will be fed into the network while training. We want to feed original images too.

I see. I don't know an elegant way for that, but with a functional model you could make a skip-connection for the input to the output of the augmentation, and then feed both into a lambda layer with a random number to decide if it takes the augmented or original image.
